# "git submodule update": how to choose value for the "--jobs" option?

Tags: git, git-submodules

The official documentation [has the following description](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#Documentation/git-submodule.txt---jobsltngt):

> **--jobs**
>
> This option is only valid for the update command. Clone new submodules in parallel with as many jobs. Defaults to the
> `submodule.fetchJobs` option.

This description is not complete to understand what value to use.

1. Do I need to set `--jobs` to be equal my Git submodules count? E.g. `--jobs $GIT_SUBMODULES_COUNT`.
2. Will I have a performance speed up if I will use a huge value, e.g. `--jobs 1000`? What are limitations and performance impacts?
3. What is `submodule.fetchJobs` option? I can not find its description in the documentation.

Comment: This just runs `git clone` in parallel. The value depends on your individual machine's CPU,memory, and disk resources. It would be very unusual that you have a repository in which this is even relevant. If you do have hundreds of submodules, just experiment -- at some point you'll reach the point of diminishing return.

Comment: It also depends on network resources. For instance, if you are going to clone 10 submodules all from the same network site and each one completely saturates the network bandwidth to that site, 1 and 10 jobs will take the same amount of wall clock time. But if you have a gigabit pipe to a main Internet backbone and you're cloning 10 submodules from all over, the speed limitation may be the one site that's behind a 64 kbit/s line.